# AddClass RemoveClass acts different on browsers

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, cross-browser

Hi I have looked over SO a lot. There are a lot of similar questions, but couldn't find my answer.

I have two checkboxes as following:

```
<div class="custom-chk">
  <label>
    <input name="Residential" id="Residential" class="upsfilter" type="checkbox" />
    Residential
  </label>
</div>
<div class="custom-chk">
 <label>
   <input name="Commercial" id="Commercial" class="upsfilter" type="checkbox" />
   Commercial
 </label>
</div>
```

I check/uncheck with following:(if one check the other uncheck)

```
$('.upsfilter').on('click', function (e) {
 if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
 $('.upsfilter').prop('checked', false);
 $('.upsfilter').parent().removeClass('checked');
 $(this).prop('checked', true);
 $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
 }
)};
```

```js
$('.upsfilter').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $('.upsfilter').prop('checked', false);
      $('.upsfilter').parent().removeClass('checked');
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
      $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
    }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-chk">
  <label>
        <input name="Residential" id="Residential" class="upsfilter" type="checkbox" />
        Residential
      </label>
</div>
<div class="custom-chk">
  <label>
       <input name="Commercial" id="Commercial" class="upsfilter" type="checkbox" />
       Commercial
     </label>
</div>
```

`label class="checked"` is showing the little custom square in checkbox.

Whit the codes above:

a) Firefox, Chrome. Check/Uncheck works but **label class="checked"** is working opposite. (showing square when checked is false)

b) IE 11 works fine

But if I remove `$(this).parent().addClass('checked');`

Firefox and Chrome work fine, but IE does the same thing (a)

Is there a compatibility issue with IE, Chrome or Firefox? IE reaction makes more sense. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I make the assumption here that your JavaScript typo/syntax issue is just a copy/paste issue here?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Which part?

Comment: Run the snippet I put the code in, see error

Comment: O yes. Fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use target where the event is attached and then toggle the classes.
After re-reading I see you want the `label` with the class so I adjusted it>

Also, you need to use the `change` event as not all actions that change it are a click.

```js
$('.custom-chk').on('change', '.upsfilter', function(event) {
  let me = $(this);
  let isChecked = me.prop("checked");
  let checks = $('.upsfilter');
  checks.not(me).prop('checked', false);
  checks.closest('label')
    .toggleClass('checked', false);
  checks.filter(':checked').closest('label')
    .toggleClass('checked', true);
});
```

```css
.checked {
  border: solid red 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-chk">
  <label>
    <input name="Residential" id="Residential" class="upsfilter" type="checkbox" />
    Residential
  </label>
</div>
<div class="custom-chk">
  <label>
   <input name="Commercial" id="Commercial" class="upsfilter" type="checkbox" />
   Commercial
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: 'I check/uncheck with following:(if one check the other uncheck)' clearly stated that if one is checked then other should be uncheck.It never stated uncheck and check the other checkbox,DV sry

Comment: Weird. Now with this, firefox, chrome and IE are all doing opposite.

Comment: I tested in Chrome and Fox, they both do the same, when checked they have a red border, when not, they do not.  Check another it unchecks and un-borders the prev checked one.

Answer (score 0):

I used `is(':checked')` to check if check box is selected and `closest('.custom-chk').siblings().find('.upsfilter')` to find the next and previous occurrence of checkbox.
Hope this is what you are looking for ,Thanks

```js
$('.upsfilter').click(function(e){
if($(this).is(':checked'))
 {
   $(this).parent().addClass('checked');         //Adding class to current checkbox
   var check =$(this).closest('.custom-chk').siblings().find('.upsfilter')
   check.prop('checked',false)
   check.parent().removeClass('checked')        //Removes class of other checkbox
 
 }
 else
  $(this).parent().removeClass('checked');  

})
```

```css
.checked
{
 color:red

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-chk">
  <label>
    <input name="Residential" id="Residential" class="upsfilter" type="checkbox" />
    Residential
  </label>
</div>
<div class="custom-chk">
 <label>
   <input name="Commercial" id="Commercial" class="upsfilter" type="checkbox" />
   Commercial
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not remove the class if it is UN checked

Comment: Well, if I run this, click to check it gets red color, if I then uncheck it stays red